# How to close app after opening browser intent

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, deep-linking

Scenario:
I have an app, let's call it app **A**.

**A** opens an activity of App **B**, using Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
*and then calls finish()*.

Problem: App **A** is still found in recent apps even though I finished its last activity. However, it's window looks black.

Question: Is it possible to detect when the "Complete action using -app-" screen is finished so I can programmatically close my app or how can I properly make sure the app is gone after going to App B?

Comment: I don't think you can remove the app from recent apps.

Comment: Yes you can, android:excludeFromRecents=true

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here:

- The list of recents is NOT a list of recent **apps**, it is a list of recent **tasks**. If you launch another `Activity`, then that `Activity` (even if it is from a different App) usually ends up in the same **task** as the `Activity` that started it.
- If you don't want your app to show up in the list of recent tasks, then you should set `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` on the root `Activity` in the manifest of your app.
- You can also launch App **B** in another task, by adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `Intent` you use to start App **B**. This will cause App **B** to run in a different task than your app **A**.
- I've no idea why, when you return to the task started by App **A**, the screen is black.